# How can I put style color on data list for a particular options?

Tags: javascript, ajax

How can I put style color on data list for a particular options? 
 Here the option flower would be in red color. what could i do for that.

```html
<input list="clr" id="coloor">  
 <datalist id="clr"> 
<option value="select" id="0"/>  
<option value="apple" id="1"/>
<option value="orange" id="2"/>
<option value="flower" id="3"/>                                   
 </datalist>
```

Comment: will a js solution do ?

Comment: yes, actually here i am appending value from js.

Comment: $.each(depDoctorss, function () {
    $('#empIdcc').append("<option value='" + this.DoctorName + "' id='" + this.DoctorId + "'>");
                        });

Comment: If you want that your option list should have color you cant do that, you can choose to have colors when selected else you can use a custom lib select2